# Django model save called twice

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a django model like this :

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=8, null=True)
    phone_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True)
    profile_pic = models.FileField(upload_to=content_file_name)
    badge = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.username

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        set_password(self=self, raw_password=self.password)
        super(UserProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

As you can see I override the `save` function to call a `set_password()` function.

For an obscure reason (or at least obscure to me) the `save` method is **called twice**. Which is a problem because it encrypts my password twice, making it impossible to retrieve afterwards.

I really have no idea why. I call this model from the tastypie API.

Tell me if you need anything else, my settings, or my imports, and I'll add them.

EDIT : The set_password code :

```
def set_password(self, raw_password):
    import random
    algo = 'sha1'
    salt = get_hexdigest(algo, str(random.random()), str(random.random()))[:5]
    hsh = get_hexdigest(algo, salt, raw_password)
    self.password = '%s$%s$%s' % (algo, salt, hsh)
```

Comment: are you calling `save` in `set_password`? also django has all this functionality built in for free https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/

Comment: @dm03514 I edited my question. I don't think self.password calls the save method..

Comment: try to set a breakpoint in the `save()` method and then look at the backtrace to see who call this function.

Comment: The problem is that every time the model is saved, the password field is taken, and hashed again (also when a user changes his phone number). I would advise to add a field hash_password, using this scenario --> if some input in password --> hash it --> store it in hash_password --> clear password input field --> store empty password field.